# "Cannot add svg image in NetworkImage in Flutter"

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to add `NetworkImage` inside `Container` but when I add `.svg` image I get error but it works for the other formats like `.png`, `.jpeg`, etc

```dart
Container(
 decoration: BoxDecoration(
  image: DecorationImage(
  image: NetworkImage("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/eb/Manchester_City_FC_badge.svg")
 )
)
```

Error:

```dart
E/flutter (22336): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/painting/codec.cc(97)] Failed decoding image. Data is either invalid, or it is encoded using an unsupported format.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Flutter Doesn't support `svg` format yet [(issue)](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15501).

You can use [flutter_svg 0.13.0+2](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg#-readme-tab-), a library to load and show `svg` files

Answer (score 0):

For my case i was consuming an endpoint with Svgs :

```
ListView.builder(
           shrinkWrap: true,
             scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
             itemCount: countries.length,
             physics: ScrollPhysics(),
             itemBuilder: (context, index){
               final Widget networkSvg = SvgPicture.network(
                   '${countries[index].flag}',
                   fit: BoxFit.fill,
                   semanticsLabel: 'A shark?!',
                   placeholderBuilder: (BuildContext context) => Container(
                       padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                       child: const CircularProgressIndicator(
                         backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
                       )),);
               return
                 Column(
                   children: [
                     ListTile(
                       title: Text('${countries[index].name}'),
                       leading: CircleAvatar(
                         backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                         child: networkSvg,
                       ),
                     )
                   ],
                 );
             });
```

Answer (score -1):

another solution using `flutter_svg` package: [info](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg)

```
final String assetName = 'assets/image.svg';
final Widget svg = SvgPicture.asset(
  assetName,
  semanticsLabel: 'Acme Logo'
);
```